# How do you display wide table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

The table is too wide, I don't want it overflow outside the screen and make browser scrollable.

I prefer the table can slide horizontal in a frame, but I need first 2 columns to be fixed, only 3rd to the last column can slide horizontal?

Do you have jQuery code example?

Or do you know any good jQuery plugins that meet my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Datatables** - http://datatables.net/

There is a jQuery adapter that has a ton of features that will allow you to create a table with a fixed column and fluid columns.  There are even ways of showing / hiding columns based off of the screen width.

**Dynatables** - http://www.dynatable.com/

This is said to be the more "fun" alternative.  It took concepts from datatables and made it more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Datatables is the most comprehensive table plugin for paginating, sorting, searching table data.  They also have a fixed column plugin, here's an example: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

Comment: the link is not working anymore. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 1):

Create two tables, one fixed and one in scrolling div. In first table, put first two columns, in second put rest of columns. Just make sure all cells are same height to get synchronized tables view

```
---------------------------------------------
|[table1]<div overflow='auto'>[table2]</div>|
---------------------------------------------
```